# Why we use throws if we could do exception handling with try catch

Tags: exception

The main aim behind the exception handling is to manage the exception which will be either at runtime or at compile time.

We have two methods for handling exception:

1. throw the exception by inserting exception Suspected code in try block and catch exception in catch block.
2. declare the exception by writing throws in from of the method.

My question is why we use this 2nd method, declaring exception?
What is the use of declaring exception, however our aim is to handle exception?
What is difference between checked and unchecked exception?

Answer (score 2):

You will declare that your method can throw a checked exception when you don't want to handle it. For example, the `FileReader` constructor is declared to throw `FileNotFoundException`. If it wasn't, it would have to handle it itself (e.g. by printing "Error: File not found" on the standard error), and you would not be able to catch it.

This ties into your second question: what is the difference between checked and unchecked exceptions. `FileNotFoundException` is a checked exception, which means you need to decide to either handle it, or to declare that you are not handling it (so that your method's caller would face the same decision). This ensures that the exception will be handled *somewhere* - if they are not, the compiler will complain. Unchecked exceptions do not need to be handled, like `OutOfMemoryError` - Java assumes you should not run out of memory; and since you can in theory run out of memory in any method, it would be ludicrous to insist that you must declare every method as a potential source of `OutOfMemoryError`.

As to which is which: `RuntimeException` and `Error` and all their subclasses are unchecked. `Exception` and its subclasses (except `RuntimeException`) are checked.

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful write-up from Oracle on the controversy of checked vs. unchecked exceptions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html).

Their suggestion is:

> Here's the bottom line guideline: If a client can reasonably be expected to 
>   recover from an exception, make it a checked exception. If a client cannot do 
>   anything to recover from the exception, make it an unchecked exception.

Depending on circumstance, it might not make sense to handle an exception in particular method, something further up in the stack might be able to make the correct action.

Consider a FileNotFoundException, sometimes it might make sense to catch an exception within a method and resolve it (load a default), but perhaps something higher up with more information about user intent will be able to make the right decision (alert them of a missing file).